# How to use Angular Module Federation to import an entire app

Tags: angular, angular-module, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I'm fairly new to Ng Module Federation, but I think I have the gist of it. My issue is that most of the references I've seen either import a single component, or a module that is lazy-loaded in the router. I would like to include an entire mini-app in a page. The general idea is to have iFrame-like behavior without an iFrame.

I have the source app exposing the app.module.ts file and this seems to be working. However, I can't figure out the syntax to import this module and use it as a component within an existing component.

I tried adding loadRemoteModule({...}) to the imports of the module that has the component that will use the nested "app view". But this is an asynchronous function, for one and two, I don't know what to do next.

Does anyone know how to import a module and use its components?

Comment: Did you get any reference for implementing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out and will try to summarize here:

- Set up the webpack for Module Federation for the Module you wish to expose "as normal". This is where you will get the exposed URL to use below. Reference here: [https://module-federation.github.io/blog/get-started#:~:text=%3E%20yarn%20dev-,Start,-Federating](https://module-federation.github.io/blog/get-started#:%7E:text=%3E%20yarn%20dev-,Start,-Federating)
- In the shell app (the one to consume the federated module):

  - create the "remotes:" section with a name for the remote module and the URL.

    ```
       remotes: {
          'myMicroFE@https://mywebsite.com/myMicroFE.js'
       }
    ```
- Create the parent component that will house the MicroFE with something like this in the template:

  ```
     <app-micro-fe-component></app-micro-fe-component>
  ```

  and similar code in the .ts file:

  ```
   async ngOnInit() {
    const appModule: NgModule = await loadRemoteModule(
    {
     remoteEntry: 'https://mywebsite.com/myMicroFE.js',
     remoteName: 'myMicroFE',
     exposedModule: './AppModule',
    }
   );
   const appModuleRef: NgModuleRef<any> = createNgModuleRef(
    appModule['AppModule'],
    this.injector
   );
   const microFEComponent = this.vcref.createComponent(
    appModuleRef.instance.getComponent()
   );
  // Sample interaction with the component.
  this.renderer.listen('window', 'message', (event) => {
    if (event.data && event.data.providerId) {
      this.microFEClicked.emit(event.data);
    }
   });
   ...
  ```

Obviously, names like MyMicroFE are here for readability, you'd use your own names.